# Make async call inside DrawerNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using a DrawerNavigation for my app. On the drawer, I need to show the logged in user's name. The logged in user object is saved in async storage. How can I make an async call from within my drawer navigation to fetch that object?

Here is what my drawer navigator looks like:

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
{
    Tabs: {
        screen: MyTabNavigator
    },
    Key1: {
        screen: Navigator1
    }
    .
    .
    .
},
{
    contentComponent: (props) => {
        return <View>
            <View style={styles.drawerHeaderStyle}>
                // Show user's name here.
                <Text style={styles.drawerHeaderTextStyle}>{`Welcome user`}</Text>
            </View>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <View style={styles.emptySpace} />
            <Touchable
                onPress={() => {
                    // Logout User
                }}
                style={styles.logoutButton}
                background={Touchable.Ripple('grey')}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonFont}>{"Logout"}</Text>
            </Touchable>
        </View>
    }
});
```